# Find Two Sets of Python Numpy Arrays on Common Column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge

I'm trying to merge some data and I have the following two 2d numpy arrays (**a** and **b**)

```
a = [[  10   9.689474368e-04][  20   6.88780375e-04]
     [  30   4.296339997e-04][  40  -1.06232578e-03]
     [  50  -1.219884414e-03][  60  -1.27936723e-03]]

b = [[  30   6.687897368e-04][  40   2.887890375e-04]
     [  50   3.293467897e-04][  60  -8.067893578e-03]
     [  70  -7.213988414e-03][  80  -8.278967323e-03]]
```

I would like to get 2 new 2d numpy arrays (**c** and **d**) where the first cols of **a** and **b** match like the following;

```
c = [[  30   4.296339997e-04][  40  -1.06232578e-03]
     [  50  -1.219884414e-03][  60  -1.27936723e-03]]

d = [[  30   6.687897368e-04][  40   2.887890375e-04]
     [  50   3.293467897e-04][  60  -8.067893578e-03]]
```

Does anybody know of an optimised way of doing so?

I've tried simple looping through each item, however it's not fast enough and I know it can be solved with a much more elegant approach.

I'm playing around with the following solution. It's much faster but not sure if it is the correct approach.

```
aHash = map(tuple, a)
bHash = map(tuple, b)

aKey = {x[:1] for x in aHash}
bKey = {x[:1] for x in bHash}

c = np.array([x for x in bHash if x[:1] in aKey])
d = np.array([x for x in aHash if x[:1] in bKey])
```

Thanks

Comment: looks like fun, but what have you tried? (we like to encourage learning and obstruct laziness here ;-)

Comment: so far not much, just a simple loop on each item, however as you can imagine its very slow.....

Comment: tack it onto the question then, don't be shy.  (i'm playing spot the difference, why don't you expand on what goal is whilst we're at it).

Comment: yeah I could expand on the goal however I don't think it's relevant. I believe the problem is pretty self explanatory as it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I would expect to be quite fast,  especially on presorted data.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[  20  ,6.88780375e-04],
     [  30 ,  4.296339997e-04],[  40 , -1.06232578e-03],
     [  50  ,-1.219884414e-03],[  60 , -1.27936723e-03],[  10  ,9.689474368e-04],])

b = np.array([[  30 ,  6.687897368e-04],[  40  , 2.887890375e-04],
     [  50 ,  3.293467897e-04],[  60 , -8.067893578e-03],
     [  70 , -7.213988414e-03],[  80 , -8.278967323e-03],])

a.sort(axis=0)
b.sort(axis=0)

def merge(a, b):
    c = []
    d = []
    ai = 0
    bi = 0
    while(ai < len(a) and bi < len(b)):
        av = a[ai]
        bv = b[bi]
        if av[0] == bv[0]:
            c.append(av)
            d.append(bv)
            ai += 1
            continue
        if av[0] < bv[0]:
            ai += 1
            continue
        else:
            bi += 1
            continue

    return np.array(c), np.array(d)


print merge(a,b)
```

Here is a comparison to the only other currently posted method.  This uses the original array slightly unsorted (I wanted to apply some penalty to the sorting method)

```
Full tests done 100,000 times
while_loop_method = 3.19426544412 sec
hash_map_method = 3.89232874699 sec
```

Here is a smaller scale comparison on a shuffled array 1000 times larger.

```
Full tests done 1,000 times
while_loop_method = 24.1850584226
hash_map_method = 25.9077035996
```

My method appears to scale up fairly well but its not nearly as efficient on unsorted large arrays.  I would expect my appending to the list to be the main culprit.

Comment: There is probably room for improvement here,  but this approach should be quite effective towards your goal.

Comment: thanks i'll try it out, im guessing your comparison is with my hash map method right?

Comment: Indeed.  An optimization you could make would be to make 2 empty np.arrays as large as "a" or "b", whichever is smaller.  Then you could simply add each value to the premade arrays by index rather than continuously appending.  As a final step you would trim off the unused indexes.

It should be noted that duplicate values in col 1 are undefined behavior...You might need to make special logic to handle that if need be.